# Ho can I unpack single-item tuples inside a list?

Tags: python

I am facing a problem with all my list items. The list shows like:

```
[('abc',), ('def',), ...]
```

I want the list to be like this:

```
['abc', 'def', ...]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why did you put the items in tuples in the first place?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't make any sense. You should update it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli it doesn't make sense *to you* because you are familiar with Python. I agree this should be rephrased though.

Comment: @CorentinPane how does it make sense in any way? Title says "How do I remove unwanted characters from my list items?", then the question that is asked is how to unpack a tuple. In other words, *nothing* needs to be removed, and it's not even clear what is "unwanted" or why.

Comment: @Abhishek I feel sorry for you, hopefully you found the answer you wanted though.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli the asker has posted the output they are getting, and the output they are wanting. These outputs differ by a few characters, `(` `,)`, hence they are asking how to remove those characters which are unwanted

Comment: @Abhishek I've updated the title for you to better reflect the wanted result, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list contains [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of strings, not directly strings. They are not unnecessary characters, they indicate that you have tuples.

You could unpack every 1-uple in your list using list comprehension:

```py
myList = [('abc',), ('def',)]

myNewList = [a[0] for a in myList] #['abc','def']
```

Comment: additionally look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) for "flattening" lists of lists

Answer (score 0):

these are list of tuples you have iterate twice

list_ = [('abc',),('def',)]

for i in list_:

```
for j in i:
    print(j)
```

out put will be in single elements then you can make a new list and append these elements.